# I am try to fetch the data from sql server through WCF service

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, codable

```
import UIKit

public struct student: Decodable {
    let id:Int
    let name:String
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func btnshow(_ sender: Any) {

        let link = "http://10.211.55.3/WcfService1/Service1.svc/GetData"
        guard let url = URL(string: link)else{
            print("error during connection")
            return
        }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

            guard let data = data
                else{                    print("there is no data")
                return
            }
            do{
                let students = try JSONDecoder().decode(student.self, from: data)
                print(students)


            } catch{
                print("conversion error")
                print(error)
            }
        }.resume()            
    }
}
```

> keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "id", intValue: nil),
>   Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No
>   value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"id\", intValue:
>   nil) (\"id\").", underlyingError: nil))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the error printed out is pretty self explanatory. The data you got is not formatted the way you're expecting it and some keys are missing (the `id` key) so `JSONDecoder()` can't decode it.

Make sure that the response you got is properly formatted before trying to decode it.

EDIT: So after seeing your comment, your model doesn't match the JSON you're receiving, it should be something like this :

```
import UIKit

public struct JsonStudent: Decodable {
    let students: [Student]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case students = "GetDataResult"
    }
}

public struct Student: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func btnshow(_ sender: Any) {
        let link = "http://10.211.55.3/WcfService1/Service1.svc/GetData"

    guard let url = URL(string: link) else {
            print("error during connection")
            return
    }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data
                else {                    print("there is no data")
                return
            }
            do {
                let students = try JSONDecoder().decode(JsonStudent.self, from: data)
                print(students)
            } catch {
                print("conversion error")
                print(error)
            }
        }.resume()            
    }
}
```

Comment: So it confirms that you are not getting an `id` and a `name` in your response !

Comment: It depends on your infrastructure. I don't know what returns your server. Try to log and/or inspect your response.

Comment: {"GetDataResult":[{"id":1,"name":"saqib               "},{"id":2,"name":"waqas               "},{"id":3,"name":"ali                 "}]}

Comment: function return these three object of json but in application it does't work.

Comment: Sorry, I edited again (forgot to modify the JsonDecoder)

Comment: JsonStudent(students: [database.Student(id: 1, name: "saqib               "), database.Student(id: 2, name: "waqas               "), database.Student(id: 3, name: "ali                 ")]) its give me this result

Comment: sir one more thing now i wanna break the data in two arrays one for ids and other for names  would you like to help me..???

Comment: `let ids = students.students.map { $0.id }` and `let names = students.students.map { $0.name }`